# @Selector nothing happen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I Know this is probably very easy question, but i can't do that, i am using @selector to dismiss a view, writing this code, nothing happen:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

//here create my button

    dismiss                 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    dismiss.frame           = CGRectMake(100, 10, 60, 50);
    [dismiss setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [dismiss setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [dismiss addTarget:self action:@selector(closeView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:dismiss];
}

//here the function

- (void)closeView {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But nothing happen, where am I doing mistake?

thanks

Comment: your closeview method exicuting or not ?

Comment: it happens probably because your view controller is not a modal view therefore there is nothing to be dismissed – have you tried to invoke the `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];` method instead?

Comment: yes when i tap on dismiss button, calling my void, but nothing happen

Comment: yes is a modal view. I try with popView but nothing. how can dismiss a subview? (probably is possible the subView issue)

Comment: because i loading a view controller main, then create a subview with other class.h/.m file, so is probably i have to unload first my class and after dismiss a view, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the `addTarget` line of code after  `[self.view addSubview:dismiss];` and check

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you're trying to do. `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` will dismiss a controller that has been presented with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, if there is no controller presented, it won't do anything.